# How to create a Double value from a Float value in Swift

Tags: swift, types, casting, primitive-types

I can't believe that I can't figure this out myself and I also cant find an answer online, but...

I'm working in Swift after a long break working on Dart and Java.

I have a situation where I have component A supplying a Float value, and component B requiring a Double value.  I can't figure out how to convert/cast/re-instantiate the float to a double!

Example:

```
let f:Float = 0.3453
let d:Double = f
```

That assignment doesn't work, even though if f had been an Int, it would have.  Which is very surprising to me since a Float is less precise than Double (takes less memory).

I also tried:

```
let d:Double = f as! Double
```

XCode warns that this will "always fail."

Also tried:

```
let d:Double = Double(from: f)
```

XCode warns "f should be decoder type"

There has to be an extremely obvious/easy solution to this.

Comment: try `let d = Double(f)`

Comment: You may wish to read the [Numeric Type Conversion](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html#ID324) section (as well as the rest) of the Swift book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @workingdog said, this will work:

```swift
let f: Float = 0.3453
let d: Double = Double(f)

print(d) // prints 0.34529998898506165
```